# SQL Server: Adding up a column sequentially

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following data:

```
ID        Characteristic     Number
1               A               3
2               B               4
3               A               1
4               A               6
```

I want a resulting table that adds up the number column like this:

```
ID        Characteristic     Number          Sum
1               A               3             3
2               B               4             7
3               A               1             8
4               A               6             14
```

Basically, it adds the new number to the previous sum and is ordered by the ID.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can just use the ANSI-standard cumulative sum function:

```
select id, characteristic, number, sum(number) over (order by id) as [sum]
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL (>2012), you can just use the `sum` function:

```
select id, characteristic, number, sum(number) over (order by id) as [sum]
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Std cumulative sum

```
select t1.*, SUM(t2.Nuber) as sum
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.Number
order by t1.id;
```